# AJAX: How can I return an object to jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm wondering if I can return an object from `json_encode()` to JQuery.  If I were to do something like this...

```
$.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   url  : 'next.php',
   dataType : 'json',
   data     : { nextID : 2 },
   success  : function ( data ) {

            // do something with data.myObject.memberVariable

          },
      error    : function ( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

           //  didn't work!

      }
});
```

AND this (next.php)

```
<?php

include_once('myClass.php');

$myObj = getMyObject( $_POST['nextID'] );  // get an object

$return['myObject'] = $myObj;

echo json_encode($return);

?>
```

Now I've tested this method but whenever i try to do `data.myObject.memberVariable` all i get is `[object Object]`.  How can I actually access the variables of the object?  Hopefully the code above helps explain my question :(

Comment: Did you look at the raw JSON?

Comment: Trying to find out how exactly to do that. I've only just recently looked into this following a tutorial I've found.

Comment: Just run `next.php` in your browser. The raw json should just echo out on the screen according to your script. You should be able to hit 'view source' to look at it. For ease of testing you could change the POST type to GET so you can debug using urls like `next.php?nextID=2`

Comment: Ok I think I have the raw JSON...

{"images":[{},{},{},{}],"error":false,"id":"3","date":"10 \/ 2010","title":"Quick Ship"}


 So the 4 {} are myObjects.  I guess since I have an array of myObjects I have to do something like: data.myObjects[0].m_url - but that didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this ?

```
 echo json_encode($return['myObject']);
```

And did you return json header?

Comment: I think you were right all along I just didn't understand it at the time. :( Anyways here is my final solution for anyone interested. I had to modify it from my code to shorten it down hopefully nothing got lost in translation. 
http://pastebin.com/aiWkM9vX

Answer (score 1):

Your `memberVariable` contains an object.
To see raw data, look at the objects properties:

```
alert(data.myObject.memberVariable.someProperty);
```

Comment: The alert function helps with debugging thanks. It says "undefined" - does it matter that my class is made in php? Here's an example of my Class..

http://pastebin.com/BVfuVx1g

So when I'm trying to access the $m_url I did...

alert(data.myObject.m_url);

Yet like I've said it returns "undefined" in my alert box.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe parse $myObj on json_encode

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers/questions:

1. You should do a
   `print_r($myObj)` to make sure that
   your object is valid and has valid
   data members. `memberVariable` is an
   object itself as SLaks pointed out,
   and that's why you're getting
   `[object Object]`.
2. echo out `$return` after you've run `json_encode()` on it and check if the JSON response is valid, and that the member variables you're looking for is correct. [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) can format your JSON for easier reading.
3. How does the `getMyObject()`
   function work? When you echo
   `$myObj->m_url` does that return
   anything?
4. Lastly, you may want to install
   [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) if you're using
   Firefox, or Inspector if
   you're using a Webkit browser, and
   use `console.log(object)` rather
   than using `alert(object)`. This will give you a more in-depth look at your object rather than `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your JQuery success function:

```
alert(data.ObjectProperty);
```

You can access the object's properties using period(.).